# jUnit mock to test and code cover IOException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have the following code snippet:

```
try {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
        String accessKey = properties.getProperty("");
        String secretKey = properties.getProperty("");
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException io) {
        log.error("Properties file not found.");
        return null;
    } catch (IOException io) {
        log.error("Error loading property.");
        return null;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException io) {
        log.error("Access Key or Secret key not present/found");
        return null;
    }
```

in jUnit, I am able to test and cover for success, `FileNotFoundException` and `IllegalArgumentException`, but unable to cover and test for `IOException` in this case. I am new to writing tests. I have also tried understanding mockito but couldn't find a way to do for this case.

Comment: Try giving invalid property in the property file. Like instead of `key=value` format, give some invalid format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using PowerMockito.mockNew (https://automationrhapsody.com/mock-new-object-creation-powermock/) to mock creating new Properties object. Then you can mock an exception to that